# Nested flutter navigation inside tab view

Tags: flutter

I have multiple tabs say Tab A, Tab B and Tab C and I have to show multiple screens in each tab say 5 screens in each tab. Now when I change screen it should keep the status of tabs intact and only screen inside the specific tab should change.

Is there  way I can use routing to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.